# Type inference failed. Firebase JobDispatcher

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-job-dispatcher

I'm facing the following error on this line: `.setService(LocationFirebaseJobService::class.java)`:

Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is `Class<LocationFirebaseJobService>` but `Class<out JobService!>` was expected

Here is my code:

```
val dispatcher = FirebaseJobDispatcher(GooglePlayDriver(context))

            val myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                    .setService(LocationFirebaseJobService::class.java)         
                    .setTag("my-unique-tag")                                    
                    .build()
```

My LocationFirebaseJobService class:

```
class LocationFirebaseJobService: JobService() {

    override fun onStartJob(p0: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onStopJob(p0: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that you extend proper JobService?
Firebase provides `com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService` but Android after API level 21 provides `android.app.job.JobService` (Firebase is compat version of this API)

Check your imports in LocationFirebaseJobService